# Java: After 5 minutes java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer | Even after SSLContextFactory

Tags: java, rest, java-8, httpurlconnection, httpconnection

Server has limit of 10 Minutes or more.

It is working fine when I curl from server itself and access from my browser (chrome or opera)

when i try from Java code (1.8):

```
try {
            URL url = new URL("https://masterdata.shintegrator.cosang.net/TerpService/api/test");
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");  
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000);
            
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    jsonString.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Success : " + jsonString.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I get following:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1690)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:788)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:723)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:747)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1676)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1577)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at com.evry.integrator.azureTest.util.MainProg.main(MainProg.java:68)
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1045)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:82)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:400)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:976)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1048)
    ... 10 more
```

Workaround:
I tried https://javabreaks.blogspot.com/2015/12/java-ssl-handshake-with-server-name.html and it didn't work

I have also tried:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sslContext = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault();
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

and also tried using getINstance("") and it did not work either.

Also tried System.getProperties().setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1,SSLv3"); but no success

and even not work when use HttpURLConnection.

Not sure if i need to do some settings somewhere or use some library?

Comment: Maybe try `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose:keymanager:trustmanager -Djava.security.debug=access:stack`  to get the details of the conversation between you app and the server. e.g. 'Negotiated protocol version:'

Comment: @cogitoboy:

It is already in logs

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2022-05-17 16:29:48.838 IST|ServerHello.java:987|Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.2.......but i don't actually understand what more to see, it is huge 4000 lines logs

Comment: @fatherazrael have you found the root cause? I have a similar issue with also 5 minutes

Comment: @DavidAguirre: For me, It is working fine for me from Chrome, ARC and Curl command..... But it is not working for Postman, Java Client (and customer too who is on Java).... Tried various ways using Postman (all settings) but not working. ..Something from certificate angle would try with Java client. 

But Since i got my customer to use alternative approach i.e pagination or multithreading; so this task jumps to low priority. But still it is an issue. 

Next week will start with this, if you have any findings kindly do share. Also will try cogitoboy way too.